# Plotly Weekly & Monthly Range selector buttons not working on time series data

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am having last 1 year time series financial data. I removed weekends as no data is present.

I created plotly viz, `2w`,`1m` range selector buttons are not showing correct time range.
While `YTD`,`6m`,`all` showing correct data.

`2w` button showing 2 week forward days but there is no data, i want to see last two week and 1m data.

Reproducable Code-

```
# !pip install investpy
import pandas as pd
import investpy
import datetime
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.express as px

today = datetime.now()  #Today Datetime
today_fut = today.strftime("%Y,%m,%d") #Converting today date to string format "%Y,%m,%d"
today_fut = datetime. strptime(today_fut, '%Y,%m,%d').date() #Converting today's date to "date" format for NSE Tools library
today = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") #Converting today date to string format "%d/%m/%Y"
one_year= datetime.today() - timedelta(days=370) #Subrtracting todays date with 370 Days
one_year = one_year.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") #Converting into  string format "%d/%m/%Y"

df = investpy.get_index_historical_data(index="Nifty 50",country="India",from_date=str(one_year),to_date= str(today))
print("Investpy NF Dataframe",df.tail())

bnf = investpy.get_index_historical_data(index="Nifty Bank",country="India",from_date=str(one_year),to_date= str(today))
print("Investpy BNF Dataframe",bnf.tail())

fig = go.Figure(data = [ go.Scatter(x = df.index,y = df['Close'],line=dict(color = 'Steelblue',width=2),mode='lines+markers',name = 'NIFTY'),
                        go.Scatter(x = bnf.index,y = bnf['Close'],line=dict(color = 'yellowgreen',width=2),mode='lines+markers',name = 'BANK NIFTY'),
                        ])
fig.update_layout(
    title='NF and BNF',template = 'plotly_dark',xaxis_tickformat = ' %d %B (%a)<br> %Y',
    yaxis_title='NF & BNF',yaxis_tickformat= "000",yaxis_side = 'right',xaxis_title='Date',legend = dict(bgcolor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'))

layout = go.Layout(showlegend=True)

##https://plotly.com/python/legend/
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    yanchor="top",
    y=0.99,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0.01  ))
#hide weekends
fig.update_xaxes( rangeslider_visible=True, rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]) ])
##https://plotly.com/python/legend/
fig.update_layout(legend=dict(
    orientation="h",
    yanchor="bottom",
    y=1.02,
    xanchor="right",
    x=1
))


config = dict({'scrollZoom': False})

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(rangeselector=dict(buttons=list([
               dict(count=14,label="2w",step="day",stepmode="todate"),
               dict(count=1,label="1m",step="month",stepmode="backward"),
               dict(count=3,label="3m",step="month",stepmode="backward"),
               dict(count=6,label="6m",step="month",stepmode="backward"),
               dict(count=1,label="YTD",step="year",stepmode="todate"),
               dict(step="all") ])),rangeslider=dict(visible=True),type="date"))
fig.update_layout(
                  xaxis_rangeselector_font_color='white',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_activecolor='red',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_bgcolor='green',
                 )
 
fig.show()
pio.write_html(fig, file='wrong_range_selecor_for-2w&1m_button.html', auto_open=True)
```

Pls let me know , if there is any bug in plotly range selector or I am doing something wrong in `xaxis=dict(rangeselector=dict(buttons=list([xaxis=dict(rangeselector=dict(buttons=list([` code.

Snap- When I click on `2w` but it show future dates, where no data is present in dataframe.

[image: 2w button range slider]
`1m` button snap-
[image]

Comment: May be replace todate with backward in ``dict(count=14,label="2w",step="day",stepmode="todate")``

Comment: i tried but still same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it seems like a bug with the range selector (`type='date'`). It occurs when setting the scatter plot mode to `'markers'` or `'lines+markers'` : in fact, using markers leads to the addition of an extra range added to the xaxis, extending the default date range from the input data.

So when you click on `2w`, the slider goes from that out-of-range date (in the future) back to 2w before that date, the same happens with the other ranges actually, not only `1m`, but it is less noticeable for bigger ones.

You could set a fixed range to circumvent the problem using `rangeslider_range` and `range` :

```py
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeslider_visible=True,
    rangebreaks=[dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"])],
    range=[df.index[0], df.index[-1]],
    rangeslider_range=[df.index[0], df.index[-1]]
)
```

...until you click on "all". The problem is that the range selector button `step='all'` will always reset the layout to use the extended range.

This does not happen when you set the scatter mode to just `mode='lines'`. In this case the default/'all' slider range fits the data.

So I guess the quick fix is to remove markers, the long one is to use Dash callbacks to have a full control of what the buttons do.